# Spacing between col in row

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, row, col

I have pages with containers that contain rows containing columns. 
I would like to enlarge the space between my columns

Here’s the code from my front page.
The first column of my second row must be the size of the first 2 columns of my first row.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 card">
    row 1 col 1
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 card">
    row 1 col 2
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 card">
    row 1 col 3
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 card">
    row 2 col 1
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 card">
    row 2 col 2
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For my second page, here is the code

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 card">
    row 1 col 1
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4 card">
    row 1 col 2
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I am this currently 
[Current Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wz0j.png)

I want to expand the space between my columns. And that on the second line, while enlarging my margins, that the first column remains aligned with the first 2 of the first line

I have redone my page with flex but I still can’t align the first column of my second line with the first 2 of the first line

```
 <div class="container">
<h3>Title</h3>

<div fxLayout="row" class="flex-row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="16px" fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <mat-card class="bloc-section" fxFlex="33.3%">           
    row 1 col 1
  </mat-card>

  <mat-card class="bloc-section" fxFlex="33.3%">           
    row 1 col 2
  </mat-card>

  <mat-card class="bloc-section" fxFlex="33.3%">           
    row 1 col 3
  </mat-card>
</div>

<div fxLayout="row" class="flex-row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="16px" fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <mat-card class="bloc-section" fxFlex="67%">
    row 2 col 1
  </mat-card>

  <mat-card class="bloc-section" fxFlex="33%">           
    row 2 col 2
  </mat-card>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? From the HTML your condition is met... Do you just need to add margins / padding?
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8JDWLUPTDEK

Comment: This link displays columns below each other

Comment: And? If you have two rows that would be the case. Having two rows (one with 3 columns and one with 2) each row would be the same code as what you want for each row. In short, your question (and not to be mean) isn't very good / clear.

Comment: I’ve updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add css like this

```
.container .row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And fix your template

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 card">
    row 1 col 1
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4 card">
    row 1 col 2
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It doesn’t work at all. It even breaks the whole design

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to copy the code. Try to understand the concept so you can create any grade.

At Bootstrap we have **12 columns** (**per row**). This means that each row must be assigned to 12 columns

**You should also know that:** Bootstrap 3.

Note: It's different in [Bootstrap 4](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp).

- xs: screens less than 768px wide
- sm: screens equal to or greater than 768px wide
- md: screens equal to or greater than 992px wide
- lg: screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide

**Your example:**
In the first row, we have 3 equal columns: `12 / 3 = 4`
In the second row, we have 2 columns.
That First column = first two columns in the previous row: `4 + 4 = 8`

**Example for xs: `< 768px`** 

Affects all sizes.

```css
.row div div{
    border-radius: 10px;
     border: 2px solid;
      background:#ddF;
      text-align:center;
    }
  
  .row.mar{
      margin-top:2px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><div>.col-xs-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><div>.col-xs-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><div>.col-xs-4</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mar">
    <div class="col-xs-8"><div>.col-xs-8</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><div>.col-xs-4</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example for sm:  `>= 768px`**

As a result, the size of each column is 12 (total). for less than 768px

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><div style="background:#ddd;">.col-sm-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><div style="background:#ddd;">.col-sm-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><div style="background:#ddd;">.col-sm-4</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8"><div style="background:#ddd;text-align: center;">.col-sm-8</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><div style="background:#fdd;">.col-sm-4</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Custom example:**

- First row:
  Only `xs-4.` For all sizes. Affects all sizes because no other size is defined.
- Second row:
  `xs-4 and 4`  `md-7 and 5`  `lg-6 and 6` ( > 1200 (6) **and** > 992px(7,5) **and** other sizes(4))

```css
  .row div p{
    border-radius: 10px;
     border: 2px solid;
      text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><p style="background:#E9F9B9;">All-4</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><p style="background:#ddd;">All-4</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><p style="background:#E9FCF9;">All-4</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-7 col-lg-6"><p style="background:lavender;">xs-4  md-7  lg-6</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-5 col-lg-6"><p style="background:#FFF1F4">xs-4  md-5  lg-6</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Using flexbox

[image]

If you use Bootstrap 4, you don't need CSS code.

```css
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
    background-color: lavender;
}

.col-4,.col-8{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.col-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
}

.col-8{
    flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
    max-width: 66.666667%;
}

.flex-container > div div{
  background:#E4F1F6;
  padding:2px 6px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="col-4"><div>1</div></div>
  <div class="col-4"><div>2</div></div>
  <div class="col-4"><div>3</div></div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="col-8"><div>A</div></div>
  <div class="col-4"><div>B</div></div>
</div>
```

### B

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: lavender;
  color: black;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.3%;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">1</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">2</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">3</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="flex-grow: 2; width: 67%;">A</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example with the col, I see no gap between the col

Comment: In the flexbox example, the first column of the second row is not aligned with the first 2 columns of the first row

Comment: Edited. If I understand you correctly, you must learn the basics. Good luck.

Comment: I tried using them fxLayout and fxFlex but it always makes me a lag

Comment: Use the first flexbox at the top. Then paste your content into the code, without changing the code. Without Bootstrap 4, you don't need CSS code(Flex first). If you still have problems, I'm at your service. You can submit your code. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

You are basically doing exactly what you should. You want the bootstrap md-X columns to handle most of the formatting.

However, your inner elements are what you want to align, more specifically you should probably add some:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8K0XRXB2V8B

[image: 2 and 3 columns rows]

And the html / CSS to get it to look this way:

```
<style>
    .filler {
        border-radius: 15px;
        border-style: solid;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row wide-fill">
    <div class="col-sm-4 spacy" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <div class="filler">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 spacy" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <div class="filler">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 spacy" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <div class="filler">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 spacy" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <div class="filler">.col-sm-8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 spacy" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
            <div class="filler">.col-sm-4</div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don’t want rounded frames me. And between the columns I want spaces. The they are glued in the example. The colors are glued

Comment: @totot this was meant to be a very clear example of how it works. Remove the rounded borders and colors if that's what you want ... But the concept seems to be exactly what you want

Comment: This does not know the different CSS classes used. I am under angular. I do not know if there is another way to cut my page

Comment: No, it doesn't. From what you've posted it doesn't need to show these things. @totot if you can't get this to work, it isn't because of the html or css I provided. It's because your question apparently doesn't provide all the necessary details. Angular is a great framework, but doesn't change the way bootstrap, css or HTML works. Case and point, the same thing working as your question describes in Angular with bootstrap https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyo87x

Comment: I have redone my page with flex but I still can’t align the first column of my second line with the first 2 of the first line

Comment: I have redone my page with flex but I still can’t align the first column of my second line with the first 2 of the first line